# Websocket Insomnia Flask

Tags: flask, websocket, insomnia

I have a short question:

I have this simple flask Server running:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    emit('message', message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
    socketio.run(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
```

and I am sending this request in INSOMNIA

[image]

But I am always getting a 400. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do a WebSocket or Socket.io?

Comment: I try to implement it with Socket.io

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `WebSocket` request to a `Socket.io` server. However, Insomnia doesn't support `Socket.io`, only `WebSocket`. You can see it [here](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/discussions/4477) and [here](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/5884).